# Placeholder for integer with unknown value

Tags: python

I am making a webscraping tool which gets the amount of players on a game server.

At the moment the most efficient method of doing this is to use Requests and BS4, to write the HTML source to a txt file, then search that file for

```
" / "
```

Unfortunately my HTML contains two forward slashed with spaces either side, so I need to be able to do something like

"%d / %d"

So it only gets the one with the integer, unfortunately I do not know the values either side, I just need it to only pick the one an integer in it.

```
prange = list(range(0, 65))
searchfile = open("data.txt", "r")
for line in searchfile:
    if " / " in line:

        print (line)
searchfile.close()
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

What you want is [using regex](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) to search for a specific pattern in your document.

`re.search(r'(\d) / (\d)', your_text)` will return all occurrences of `X / Y` where `X` and `Y` are 1-digit numbers. If you want more than one digit, you can [take a look at the regex syntax](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax), and write something like `r'(\d+) / (\d+)'`.

With your example, you should have:

```
prange = list(range(0, 65))
searchfile = open("data.txt", "r")
for line in searchfile:
    m = re.search(r'(\d+ / \d+)', line)
    if m:   
        print (line)
searchfile.close()
```

Comment: Yeah the numbers are double digit, thank you for your help. Unfortunately I am a novice at Python and will continue looking into how to to implement your method

Answer (score 1):

You can try using [re](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) to find required pattern:

```
>>> import re
>>> re.search( '(\d+)\s+/\s+(\d+)', 'dsdsd 111 / 222 dsdsds').groups()
('111', '222')
```